# Array with cell value and wildcards

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, wildcard

I'm using the following sub, but it works only if I put in the array the string i want to use (  `wat`  )

If I try to put in the array the cell where this string is (`BZ6`) the macro does not work.

- In `BZ6` I have `=Sheet1!B8`
- In `Sheet1B8` I have `wat`

Where is my mistake here?

```
Option Explicit

Sub SearchForString()

    Dim a As Long, arr As Variant, fnd As Range, cpy As Range, addr As String

    On Error GoTo Err_Execute

    'populate the array for the outer loop
    arr = Array("*" & "("BZ6")" & "*")

    With Worksheets("Sheet8")
        'outer loop through the array
        For a = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
            'locate first instance
            Set fnd = .Columns("BT").Find(what:=arr(a), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, _
                                         SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                         MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
            If Not fnd Is Nothing Then
               'record address of first find
                addr = fnd.Address
                'seed the cpy range object
                If cpy Is Nothing Then Set cpy = fnd.EntireRow
                Do
                    'build union
                    Set cpy = Union(cpy, fnd.EntireRow)
                    'look for another
                    Set fnd = .Columns("BT").FindNext(after:=fnd)
                'keep finding new matches until it loops back to the first
                Loop Until fnd.Address = addr
            End If
        Next a

    End With

    With Worksheets("sheet2")
        'one stop copy & paste operation
        cpy.Copy Destination:=.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    End With

    MsgBox "All matching data has been copied."

    Exit Sub

Err_Execute:
    MsgBox "All matching data has been copied."
Debug.Print Now & " " & Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description

End Sub
```

Comment: If you're only searching for a single value then why use `Array()` ?  Try `arr = Array("*" & sheetRef.Range("BZ6").Value & "*")` (adjust `sheetRef` to correct sheet)  if you still want to use an array.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion.   In fact I have a table and I'd need to copy just the values to another sheet (starting from C2) all the rows having the same string ( with wildcards). this string can be in different colums...   I know the array is not THE solution but it was what I thought to be able to write...  bu I wasn't :-D